# Validation on DropDownListFor problem (ModelState.IsValid always false)

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I´m having problem using validation on DropDownListFor ...

My Model :

```
public class User 
{
    ...
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role 
{        
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(new Repository<Role>().GetAll(), "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }
```

My Edit View(Strongly typed)

```
   @model User
   ...
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role)
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role.Id, ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, "-- Select --",new { @class = "form radius" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
```

All works great, the problem is fired when I tried to Save the User model :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        ...
    }
```

The ModelState.IsValid is always false... Looking inside the ModelState, the the error is in **Role.Name** key... The error is : **The Name field is required**

Is there any way to fix that ? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have placed a Required attributes on the `Name` property but this is never sent to the server so your model is not valid (only the `Id` is POSTed). So you should place it on the `Id` property:

```
public class Role 
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also you should make this `Id` property `Nullable` as you have defined an empty value for your dropdown and if the user doesn't select any value it will crash. So your model should look like this:

```
public class Role 
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Also you could remove the Required attribute from the Role property in the User class. It's not needed.

Final advice and probably the most important one: replace this `ViewBag` ugliness with a property on your view model so that the helper looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Role.Id, 
    Model.Roles, 
    "-- Select --",
    new { @class = "form radius" }
)
```

Comment: The problem is I have a Role UI where the user can register new Roles... And the required on Name is needed for that, besides my Id property belongs to EntityBase class...

Comment: @Paul then ensure that there is a `Name` input field on your form and that a value is sent or your model will never be valid. If there is no Name field then use view models. In fact, no, you should always be using view models :-)

Comment: Yes, Thats what I´m trying to do, but I dont know how :(

Comment: @Paul, you define a class that contains only the properties that are required by the given view and you have your controller action take this view model as parameter. It will contain the corresponding validation attributes. So if there is no Name in this view there will be no Name property in your `EditUserViewModel`. It's the fact that you are trying to reuse your models in different situation that's causing you headaches. Don't put this `User` model in all your actions as validation rules will differ. Define view models and then map between the view models and the model.

Comment: It eluded me for a long time what the difference was between a Model (like, what you're working with "below the Controller" down to the database and a ViewModel. Darin describes it best: If it's not in the View it shouldn't be in the class of the View's Model variable.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this kind of error.

Maybe the solution to your problem is placing a code like this in your Edit.cshtml view:

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public class Role 
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Id Required.")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required.")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.gRoles, "-- Select --")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role.Id)
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Creedit(User x)
{
    x.Role = db.RoseSet.Find(x.Role.Id);
    if (x.Role != null)
    {
        ModelState["Role.Name"].Errors.Clear();

    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // proceed
    }
    else
    {
      // return validation error
    }
}
```